# Java is class abstract?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get object from another class from another package

```
package processManager;

public class PCB {
    public int vruntime;
    public int nice_value=0;
}
```

in the same package

```
package processManager;

public class Process {

    public Process(PCB pcb) {
        this.pcb = pcb;
    }

    public Process() {
    }    

    public   PCB pcb;
    int a;
}
```

usage of object

```
package processManager.newpackage;
import processManager.Process.*;

public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Process proc=new Process();
    }
}
```

and I don't know why but then I've got "Process is abstract; cannot be instantiated"

Comment: I hardly recommended you to learn https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html before post similar question.

Comment: Code Snippets are for JavaScript/HTML/CSS code, don't use it for other languages because it won't run.

Comment: Your import is incorrect. This `import processManager.Process.*;` should be `import processManager.Process;` *or* `import processManager.*;`

Answer (score 1):

Please look closer at your code:

A) You have defined a class `processManager.Process` which is not abstract.

B) Next in the next file you are importing

```
import processManager.Process.*;
```

Which actually defines an import of all sub-classes of `processManager.Process` class (you have none) but the class itself is not considered an import.

C) This means that in the next piece of code

```
Process proc = new Process();
```

You are trying to create an instance of `java.lang.Process` [class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) which **is abstract**.

This is a source of your error.